# Error: category.product.addto.wishlist is not a child of catalogsearch.product.addto

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.2.6, wishlist

```
Magento 2.2.6

### Steps to reproduce (*)
<!---
Important: Provide a set of clear steps to reproduce this bug. We can not provide support without clear instructions on how to reproduce.
-->
```

> 1. Opening web-shop (Landing page or somewhere else) and using the search bar.
> 2. Tipping any word and pressing enter

[image: grafik]

> 3. Getting error instead of products refering to your search: 1 exception(s):
>      Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): category.product.addto.wishlist ist kein Kind von catalogsearch.product.addto

```
### Expected result (*)
1. List of products which fit my search

### Actual result (*)
```

> 1. Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): category.product.addto.wishlist ist kein Kind von catalogsearch.product.addto

[image: grafik]

> Link: https://www.dev.feelcomfort.de/catalogsearch/result/?q=Test

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Best regards,
Feelcomfort

Comment: are you also getting error in default theme ?